# what is session concept in web service? and how to implement

Tags: c#, web-services, session

I have a problem in session concept of asp.net web services, how to implement in a application?

and also i have a problem in eval in asp.net actually what is the use of eval

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" ImageUrl="~/cpanel/images/icons/table/actions-delete.png"
       runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("JobID")%>' OnClick="imgbtnDelete_Click">
```

Comment: please split your questions into two seperate ones. One for your session question one for the eval question.

Answer (score 1):

A web service generally runs in a web application just like a web site, so you have access to all the same session functionality.

See [Session State Overue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

You can store data in the session using :

```
Session["FirstName"] = "Peter";
Session["LastName"] = "Parker";
```

Retreive it using:

```
ArrayList stockPicks = (ArrayList)Session["StockPicks"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyDemo : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        // get the Count out of Session State
        int? Count = (int?)Session["Count"];

        if (Count == null)
            Count = 0;

        // increment and store the count
        Count++;
        Session["Count"] = Count;

        return "Hello World - Call Number: " + Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

[WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]-This attribute enables session in web service

From client application- on button click event we have to write this to access web service

```
localhost.MyDemo MyService;

// try to get the proxy from Session state
MyService = Session["MyService"] as localhost.MyDemo;

if (MyService == null)
{
    // create the proxy
    MyService = new localhost.MyDemo();

    // create a container for the SessionID cookie
    MyService.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    // store it in Session for next usage
    Session["MyService"] = MyService;
}

// call the Web Service function
Label1.Text += MyService.HelloWorld() + "<br />";
```

}

output will be:-
Hello World - Call Number: 1
Hello World - Call Number: 2
Hello World - Call Number: 3